# use Entity Framework sql generator manually / EF without entity data model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm looking a way to use Entity Framework to build SQL queries to DB without using Entity Data Models.

The reason why I'm looking a way to use EF is it has database providers for MySql, SQL, SQLite and I wish I had opportunity to use any of them in my projects.

There is classes that implement `DbExpressionVisitor< T >` in every provider so I think maybe there is a way to construct some `DbCommandTree` objects to pass it to `SqlProviderServices` for example.

I want to achive almost the same functionality as [dynasql](http://dynasql.codeplex.com/) or [Kerosene ORM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117666/Kerosene-ORM) has but with good community support. I know I will need to create some proxy classes to use DbExpressions in fluent way.

Comment: This makes no sense. And OR/M needs to have "O" and "R". This means that there **must** be a `Relational DB` and there `must` be an **Object Model** to map it to. What's the reason you would want not to create a proper Data Model?

Comment: The question is how to query data. And not how to map it. Object-relational-mapping its just a direction of how to make things. Look at [fluentdata](http://fluentdata.codeplex.com/) it still ORM and its pretty useful in some situations. I can map results to some object type after query is done through DbContext.DataBase.SqlQyery<T> and it's still entity framework and I still use that ORM. It has sql generator I want to use it. That is the question.